# How to set pug as the template engine

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

When setting the view engine in my project; I used this snippet of code and the app works just fine.

```
// configurations for the view engine
app.set('views', './views');
app.set('view engine', 'pug');
```

However, I have seen tutorials use a different approach where they attach "__dirName" to it. I am not well versed with express and how it works so I would love to know the functionality of the snippet of the code below. Kindly explain it to me so I can understand the applicability.

```
// configurations for the view engine
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

these 2 are different things all together..

1. `app.set('view engine', 'pug');` is used while setting the view engine. This will set the view template type.
2. `app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));` is used when you have your `pub` files to be rendered from the backend based on the routes.

Consider the case,

You have your pug files in a below fashion in your directory :

```
/views/index.pug
/views/about.pug
```

here `views` is the folder name and `index.pug` and `about.pug` are the files.
you want to render them as for the routes accordingly : `/` and `/about`

At that time,
You can use  `app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));` so that all your views be rendered from the `views` folder. ( consider : `__dirname, 'views'` )

so you can write something like this :

```
app.get('/', (req,res) => {
  res.render('index')
})

app.get('/about', (req,res) => {
  res.render('about')
})
```

so now the code automatically look for `index` file with the `.pug` extention present at the location : `__dirname, 'views'`

Hope this answer helps!! Feel free to comment if you get any doubts and also look at the blogs of express.js..

Answer (score 0):

`app.set('view engine', 'pug');` sets pug as the view engine. The code for setting it is the same for both example you provided.

---

The path that changes (`app.set('views', './views');`) is the code that tells express what directory to look in for the template files when it renders a view.

`__dirname` is the directory that the JavaScript module (e.g. `server.js`) is in. `path.join` is used to combine it with the string `views` to give you **a subdirectory called *views* in the directory *server.js* is in**.

If you don't have that, then you have a *relative* path and it will be computed from the *current working directory*.

If you were to be in `/home/users/you/project/` and type `node server.js` then it would look for views in `/home/users/you/project/views`

However, if you were in `/home/users/you/` and type `node project/server.js` then it would look for views in `/home/users/you/views` (and probably not find them because you would have put them in your project!).

In short, if you **don't** use `__dirname` then **your code will break** depending on what directory you run it from.

**Use the `__dirname` approach**.